# Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

имею такой код:

```
def reg(peer_id,name):
    try:
        global zanyat
        zanyat.append(peer_id)
        cn = checkCountUsers(name)
        name = name + str(cn+1)
        m = open('users/'+peer_id+'.json','w+',encoding='utf-8')
        m.write(json.dumps({    str(peer_id):{       "nickname":str(name),     "ballance":"0",       "keyboard":"1",      "reputation":"0",        "deals":"0",      "ogran":"1",    "role":"buy"   }}))

        m.close()
        m = open('accounts/'+peer_id+'.json','w+',encoding='utf-8')
        m.write(json.dumps({    "Yandex":"none",  "Qiwi":"none",    "WebMoney":"none",    "bank":"none",    "phone":"none"}))
        m.close()
        print('['+time.ctime()+'] Регистрация пользователя '+name)
        zanyat.remove(peer_id)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        write_msg(peer_id,'Произошла ошибка при регистрации',0)
```

При вызове функции выдаёт ошибку: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Раньше такого не было. Не могу понять, в чём дело.

Comment: Используется кодировка `UTF-8 BOM`, когда декодировка идет через `UTF-8-SIG`